# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_fix_up_module'

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I maked `py` script executable by `cx_freeze`. But while running, it has failed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.4\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze|initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
        exec(code, m.__dict__)
    File "yukle.py", line 2, in <module>
    File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.pyt", line 2214, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    bla bla bla...
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_fix_up_module'
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.4\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
        exec(code, m.__dict__)
    File "yukle.py", line 2, in <module>
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
    File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.4\lib\site-packages\dropbox\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from . import client, rest, session
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2284, in _handle_fromlist
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
    File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.4\lib\site-packages\dropbox\client.py", line 22, in <module>
        from .rest import ErrorResponse, RESTClient
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
    File "X:\Python34-x32\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
    File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.4\lib\site-packages\dropbox\rest.py", line 26, in <module>
        TRUSTED_CERT_FILE = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'trusted-certs.crt')
    File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.4\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 954, in resource_filename
        self, resource_name
    File "C:\Python\32-bit\3.4\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1640, in get_resource_filename
        "resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip"
NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip
```

I installed it from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze). But while running, it has failed.

Comment: This is a known bug in cx_Freeze when used with Python 3.4.1. Install it from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_freeze) to get a rebuilt version fixing the problem.

Comment: It has failed again.

Comment: It looks like the dropbox package doesn't like being loaded from a zip file. You might be able to work around this by copying the dropbox package into your build directory.